# How to rotate TikZ decoration (arrow)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrow-curve, tikz-decorations

While TikZ has the option of bending arrows that appear at the tip of an edge (library `bending`), and has the option of placing arrows in the middle of edges (library `decorations`), I did not manage to combine the two.  In the code below I use the library `decorations` to place an arrow near the middle of a loop, but the arrow is oriented according to the tangent to the curve at the tip.  Is it possible to bend the arrow or even just to rotate it by a hard-coded angle?

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{stealth}}},postaction={decorate}}}
  \node[draw,circle] (n) {$n$};
  \draw [->-=.5] (n) to [distance=5ex, in=60, out=120, loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circled letter with arrow looping above it: the arrow head is tangent to the point of the loop where its tip lies, instead of following the curvature of the loop]

Answer (score 8):

At the time of decoration, `\pgfdecoratedangle` holds the path tangent angle to adjust the transformation. You can use that or any hard coded value offset with this amount

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{->-/.style={
  decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {%
    \arrow[rotate=-\pgfdecoratedangle]{stealth}% always point right
    }
  },
  postaction={decorate}
  }
}

  \node[draw,circle] (n) {$n$};
  \draw [->-=.2] (n) to [distance=5ex, in=60, out=120, loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]